# Microsoft graph get user by email or Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to query get a single user details through Microsoft graph by email id, can anyone help me I couldn't find it in MS docs.

```
var users = graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

this brings only 100 users
I need to get user by email so I can get specific user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls try this code.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var temp = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("mail eq 'tiny@outlook.com'").GetAsync();
```

When we want to do a filter in Ms graph api, we may firstly check if the target property support filter, for [ms user api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), `mail` is supported.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I need to use the following for **Microsoft.Graph** v5

```cs
var user = (
    await graphServiceClient.Users
        .GetAsync(c =>
        {
            c.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "mail" };
            c.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
            c.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq {userEmail}";
        }))
    .Value?.FirstOrDefault();
```